# Why is my question closed as 'too broad'?

Tags: discussion

My question here:
[Are HDD <-> SSD transfer speeds completely bottlenecked by HDD speed?](https://serverfault.com/questions/747788/are-hdd-ssd-transfer-speeds-completely-bottlenecked-by-hdd-speed)
is very specific but was closed as 'too broad'. Maybe it doesn't look like every other question that is really verbose, but the question is quite specific.

How do I reword it without filling it with useless fluff?

Comment: Include a few specific (or even reasonably general) details about the SSD and HDD and system you're working with / planning to work with might help here.

Comment: Just a run of the mill SSD vs HDD should be similar enough no?

Comment: Well, I don't know... And neither do you, else why ask?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a Q&A site we strive for questions that result in a right and correct answer that, ideally, can also stand the test of time.

What might appear as a "simple" question to a poster is often far less so for somebody more informed or the actual specialist.

That lack of specific details will often result in the "too broad" close reason, as a "scientifically correct" answer will need to address too many underlying concepts,  variables and considerations that the OP is not aware of. The devil is in the details.

Also a genuinely simple question is often answered by doing a little background research and reading the Wikipedia article.
Simplifying and generalizing your question too much will often make it look completely hypothetical and   our community is not always too receptive of those , as the [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask) also clarifies: *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."*.

So what triggered your question?

- Academic curiosity? ==> Probably going to be closed as Off-topic or too broad.
- Actual problem? ==> Please edit and improve your question to include the relevant details of your setup as you may have reduced your question to the essentials a bit too much.

As the comments given already indicate, the information in this specific  question was insufficient to give a conclusive answer, not only are there huge differences between individual SSD's and between individual HD's, let alone between an SSD's and a random spinning HD, the drives themselves are not the only things that can be a limiting factor, there is for instance also the controller, the IO load etc.

The fastest drives in an external USB2 enclosure are still going to be performing slow in most loads.

An SSD might usually be fast, but possibly there are SSD's (maybe rare, uncommon and designed for specific industrial purposes) that are very slow in every aspect compared to an otherwise already underwhelming 4800 rpm notebook drive.

Answer (score 6):

It was specific from a fairly broad point of view; but mired in details that will change how the answer is worded depending on what you were intending to do with it. In this case, the *it depends* was strong enough to trigger a *too broad* reaction in some reason.

It was still answerable, but it still seems too broad to many.

Comment: There wasn't much in the way of research demonstrated either, which tends to have an influence on how far people are willing to stretch themselves to salvage a question that is missing the needed details.